# How to handle success and fail in redux

Tags: angular, redux

How can I handle error when I am inserting in redux? My code es:

```
async newGroup(item: Item) {
    const newGroup = new GenericEntity(null, item.text, item.textMultiLanguage);
    this.store.dispatch(new RequestAddWorkstationGroup(newGroup));
    this.messageNotify.open(this.translate.instant('common.created_ok'), 'X', true, true, 3000, 'end', 'top', true, 'success');
  }
```

I want to show a notify message when element was inserted correctly, and show another message when element was error when user try to insert the element.

Is there a way to handle error using store-redux?

Comment: read this website 
i hope it help
https://medium.com/@gausmann.simon/error-handling-in-ngrx-and-ngrx-effects-6d331c517bcc

Comment: Thanks @PiyushJain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it. We must set the handling error in effects, actions, reducers files.

In **actions**, I have to add:

```
export class CategoryFailed implements Action {
     
      static readonly TYPE = 'CATEGORY_FAILED';
      readonly type = CategoryFailed.TYPE;
      constructor(public category: GenericEntity) { }
    }


export class RequestCategoryFailed implements Action {
     
      static readonly TYPE = 'REQUEST_CATEGORY_FAILED';
      readonly type = RequestCategoryFailed.TYPE;
      constructor(public category: GenericEntity) { }
    }
```

In **reducers**:

```
case CategoryFailed.TYPE: {
      return { ...state, categories: state.categories.map(it => it.id === action.category.id ? it : it) };
    }

......TYPE:
    case RequestCategoryFailed.TYPE:
    default: { return { ...state }; }
```

In **Effects**:

```
@Effect() requestCategoryGroup: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType<RequestCategoryGroup>(RequestCategoryGroup.TYPE),
    mergeMap((category) =>
      from(this.Service.category(category.category)).pipe(
        map(() => new category(category.category)),
          catchError((error) => {
            const message = JSON.parse(error.response);
            this.dialogsService.alert(this.translate.instant('common.cannot_modify'), message.Title);
            return of(new CategoryFailed(category.category));
          }))));
```